# Password Protected AlertDialog in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

so basically I am trying to have a validator in alert dialog in Flutter ('OK' button), where when it pops out, it would show the TextFormField with input and 'OK' and 'CANCEL' buttons.

If you type in the correct password and click 'OK' in the alert dialog, it would run the _getImage() function, and if you cancelled, it just pops it off the stack.

For now, the 'Cancel' works as it should, but I am not sure how to validate the input in the onPressed for the 'OK' button. I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly with the TextFormField below or if I'm having unnecessary code. Is there a simple solution to this?

```
_showPasswordDialog() async {
return showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) {
      return AlertDialog(
        title: Text('Enter Password'),
        content: TextFormField(
          //not sure if i need this
          initialValue: _phPassword,
          controller: _textFieldController,
          decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Enter Password'),
          maxLength: 15,
          obscureText: true,
          validator: (String value) {
            if (value.isEmpty) {
              return 'Password is Required';
            }
            //maybe not necessary for toString()
            if (value == _pass.toString()) {
              _getImage();
            } else {
              return 'Please type in Correct Password';
            }

            return null;
          },
          onSaved: (String value) {
            _phPassword = value;
          },
        ),
        actions: [
          FlatButton(
            child: Text('Cancel'),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
          ),
          //this needs to validate if the typed value was the same as the
          //hardcoded password, it would run the _getImage() function
          //the same as the validator in the TextFormField
          FlatButton(
            child: Text('OK'),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
        ],
      );
    });
```

}

EDIT: So it should be something like this, correct?

```
FlatButton(
            child: Text('OK'),
            onPressed: () {
              String data = _textFieldController.value.text;

              if (data == _pass) {
                _getImage();
              } else {
                return 'Please type in Correct Password';
              }
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
          ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace you **FlatButton** with the following Codes

```
 FlatButton(
            child: Text('OK'),
            onPressed: () {
              String data = _textFieldController.value.text;
              
              if(data=='valid Password'){
                _getImage();
              }else{
                //Show Toast
                
                //Close the Dialog
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              }
              
              
            },
          ),
```

Comment: Edited the main question with sample of what I think it should look like, let me know if that's correct, I didn't have time to try it out in the emulator. Not sure where the pop should go.

Comment: i have given you the code to replace and run.not to edit the code. i have run the code. at my end and it was working.